# Who are the "shes" referring to?

Tags: sentence-construction

A sentence from wiktionary: [link](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/Isaac)

> Explained in Genesis as referring to his mother Sarah’s laughing when **she** was told **she** would have a son at her old age.

I am rather confused about the sentence.

What is the role of **Sarah's mother** in this sentence and why is **sarah** referring to his mother?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you say `Sarah's mother`? Sarah is not his name but his mother's name

Comment: *referring to his mother [**who is called Sarah**]’s laughing*

Answer (score 2):

The reference is to *Isaac's* mother, Sarah, so there is only one *she.* In the Bible story, Abraham and Sarah had their only child, Isaac, when they were elderly. There is a mistake in the Wiktionary entry; it should be *in* her old age.

Comment: It's true we're more *likely* to use ***in*** rather than ***at*** when referring to someone's ***old*** age (when it becomes a "container" metaphor for an age *range* rather than a simple "location" metaphor for the more specific ***At** your age you should know better!* usage). But there are lots of written instances of [***at his old age***.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22at+his+old+age%22) I wouldn't call it a "mistake".

Comment: Is "referring" here a "gerund" or a "participle"?

Comment: @user100323 gerunds function as  nouns in sentences and participles function as adjectives.  **as** is a preposition, so it must be followed by a noun.